# Routing to JSON responses in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

In a CakePhp Project I have an Item Model with its controller:

```
class ItemsController extends AppController{
  public $components = array('RequestHandler');

  public function data(){
    $items = $this->Item->find('all');
    $this->set('items', $items);
    $this->set('_serialize', array('items'));
  }
}
```

by specifying in the `routes.php`:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

I get the JSON response that I want when making a request to `/items/data.json`

How can I get the JSON response when calling `/items/data` ? and how can I connect the JSON response in a route. For example if I want `/data/items.php` to render the same JSON that the `/items/data.json` request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using some methods of RequestHandler in a before filter

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json');
  $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
}
```